# Magento 404 admin panel?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

I have enabled the secure URL option in magento for both frontend and for admin. After that the **admin** keyword pages without the admin after index.php in the URL are redirecting to 404 page. the pages that are without admin keyword are the extension pages that i have installed .

Any help to resolve this problem?